# django form fields clean method and security

Tags: django, forms, security

My web application has a lot of forms. I don't use django form classes, since my forms are somewhat complicated (involve with a lot of javascript), so I write the forms and handle them at server by myself.
My question is about "cleaning" the fields data.
I know django forms has a `clean()` method which supposed to sanitize the data.
But isn't django built-in ORM already clean the data from SQL injection type attacks?

If I have similar code:

```
field = request.POST['field']
record = SomeModel.objects.get(pk=record_id)
record.field = field
record.save()
```

I POSTed a < script> tag with some javascript to my server, and I couldn't find any security hole here, since django sanitize the data that is printed in the template.
so what the clean() method adds here exactly, and does this code has any security problems?

Comment: Whether or not that code has security issues depends on whether or not you use ssl. From a django pov it's fine

Comment: By security in this question I refer to the security of the server code

Answer (score 2):

The `clean()` method mainly validates the form data i.e. it verifies if the data inserted in the form fields fits the type of the field and respects some patterns. The SQL injection protection is build into ORM. So if you use django ORM querysets you should be protected from SQL injection attacks. As per [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection):

> By using Django’s querysets, the resulting SQL will be properly
>   escaped by the underlying database driver.

Only if you want to run [`raw SQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#executing-raw-queries) or [`custom SQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) queries you have to properly escape any parameters that the user can control.

Comment: So to sum this up, django forms module, and the clean method have nothing to do regarding security?

Comment: In django as in any other web framework there are many possible [security threats](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection) (read the whole section), your concern was about SQL injection. And, yes, as long as you use ORM querysets you are safe from this.